# How to extract httponly cookie from a post request in Java?

Tags: java, curl, post, cookies, jsessionid

I have the following cURL request

```
curl -i --data 'user=user1&password=password1' -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/login
```

This returns me the following response:

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
    Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
    Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization,Content-Type
    Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, HEAD, DELETE
    Date: Monday, January 22, 2017 10:07:22 AM UTC
    Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=XXXYYYZZZ; Path=/; HttpOnly
    Content-Type: application/json
    Content-Length: 118
    Server: Jetty(9.2.15.v20160210)
    {"status":"OK","message":"","body":{"principal":"user1","ticket":"el23-esedejhz943"}}
```

I want to make this call in Java, and extract the JSESSIONID present in Set-Cookie field. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a way to do it without using any external library, works for http, but not for https (because of certificates - this could be set up to work, but is too broad for this post)

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class JsessionIdExtractor {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String jSessionId = logInAndRetrieveJsessionId();
        System.out.println("JSESSIONID is: " + jSessionId);
    }

    private static String logInAndRetrieveJsessionId() throws Exception {
        String url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/login";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        // add reuqest header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Some browser name eg. fierfox");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        String postParameters = "user=user1&password=password1";
        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(postParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + postParameters);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
        return extractJsessionId(con);
    }

    private static String extractJsessionId(HttpURLConnection con) {
        Map<String, List<String>> headerFields = con.getHeaderFields();
        Set<String> headerFieldsSet = headerFields.keySet();
        Iterator<String> hearerFieldsIter = headerFieldsSet.iterator();
        while (hearerFieldsIter.hasNext()) {
            String headerFieldKey = hearerFieldsIter.next();
            if ("Set-Cookie".equalsIgnoreCase(headerFieldKey)) {
                List<String> headerFieldValue = headerFields.get(headerFieldKey);
                for (String headerValue : headerFieldValue) {
                    System.out.println("Cookie Found...");
                    String[] fields = headerValue.split(";\\s*");
                    String cookieValue = fields[0];
                    if (cookieValue.toUpperCase().trim().startsWith("JSESSIONID")) {
                        return cookieValue.split("=")[1];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("there is no JSESSIONID cookie in reponse");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.net.URLConnection;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;

    public class ResponseHeaderUtil {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

        URL obj = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:8080/login");
        URLConnection conn = obj.openConnection();
    //add reuqest header 

            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5"); 
            String urlParameters = "user=user1&password=password1";
            Map<String, List<String>> map = conn.getHeaderFields();

        System.out.println("Printing Response Header...\n");

        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey()
                               + " ,Value : " + entry.getValue());
        }

        System.out.println("\nGet Response Header By Key ...\n");
        String server = conn.getHeaderField("Server");

        if (server == null) {
            System.out.println("Key 'Server' is not found!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Server - " + server);
        }

        System.out.println("\n Done");

        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

      }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your response. But how do I pass username and password as shown in the cURL command? Only a valid username/password generates JSESSIONID.

Comment: //add reuqest header
  con.setRequestMethod("POST");
  con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
  con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

  String urlParameters = "user=user1&password=password1";

Comment: You are not using the urlParameters anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways to achieve that is to use libarary called HtmlUnit like this:

```
public void post() throws Exception

    {

        URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:8080/login");
        WebRequest requestSettings = new WebRequest(url, HttpMethod.POST);
        requestSettings.setRequestParameters(new ArrayList());
        requestSettings.getRequestParameters().add(new NameValuePair("user", "user1"));
        requestSettings.getRequestParameters().add(new NameValuePair("password", "password1"));
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        Page redirectPage = webClient.getPage(requestSettings);
        // here is your jSessionId cookie:
        Cookie jSessionId = webClient.getCookieManager().getCookie("JSESSIONID")

    }
```

You can do it even better, for example, programatically go to login page, then enter the password in password field, username in username filed (using selectors aka jQuery to select fields), then get the form, submit it and then read cookies. Read the HtmlUnit documentation for further information - it is really great library.

Comment: is there a way to do this without using that library?

Comment: Yes, there is, check my answer again